ChromeDriver vs. ChromeExtension which one to use?
My goal is to develop a tool that can interact with existing sites (read information or navigate and click), do some simple computations , save data in some database (the tool's memory).
So I had chance to know ChromeDriver and also ChromeExtension. To me they both can do similar stuff: read html elements, simple computations, interact with the site (click, fill in details etc).
Am I right ?
So how do I decide which to chose for my project?
Notes:
I know that

chomedriver requires installation. That is fine.
The chrome extension might have less permissions. I am afraid this will affect me when interacting with remote database but I am not sure.
I used chromedriver in python (i feel more comfortable developing in python)

Thanks

this probably comes down to how you deliver this tool.  It's worth noting that the early versions of Selenium were browser extensions that would record/playback actions, so much of the work is already done there. (might have to be updated for current browser support, though.)
